# Android - WebView Zoom/Pan Images

Tags: android, webview

I need the common functionality of zooming & panning around an image that is larger than the device's screen. After much searching I settled on WebView as the solution, using its built-in zoom & pan.

There is an I haven't been able to solve with WebView: I can set the initial WebView zoom to some value but I have not found a way to make WebView set the initial zoom level to make the image just fit right, independent of the WebView and device size. In other words, when I first load an image I want it to always fully display indepndent of image and device size.

Any ideas?

Alternatively, it seems this is a pretty common functionality and I would assume there is some ImageView component out there with the zoom/pan functionality defined in a best-in-class way. Perhaps Google releasing a component as they use in their own Android photo galleries. Is there such a thing? I am not skilled enough to be able to extract this out of the whole Android source release.

Answer (score 1):

We haven't put out a specific component for this so far because it's not something that generalizes terribly well with what most developers want to do. The simple photo viewer case that you describe is about as far as it gets. (Maybe we'll do a support library widget or something for that case someday.) Beyond that apps tend to have highly custom ways of rendering and representing content that they want to pan and zoom around. Maps uses custom drawing of tiles and vectors, WebView renders directly from webkit and needs to represent position and zoom in a way that works well with that, the new Android 4.0 Calendar that was demoed expands or contracts the available area for text, etc. With such different scenarios there isn't really a one-size-fits-all solution that wouldn't be suboptimal for most uses.

That said, what you're trying to do is one of the simpler cases and a WebView is overkill. [This Android Developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) and its accompanying sample code should set you on the right track.